# Nodejs util.inherits produce unexpected results

Tags: node.js

Following code always prints **3 3**  where as it should be printing **2 3** anything in any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here ? or this is expected ?

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
    util=require('util');
var Car=function(){
    var self=this;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    var make=1;
    Car.prototype.getMake = function() {
        return make;
    };
    Car.prototype.setMake = function(val) {
        make=val;
        return make;
    };
}
util.inherits(Car, EventEmitter);

function Bmw(){
    Car.call(this);
}

function Merc(){
    Car.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Bmw, Car);
util.inherits(Merc, Car);

var car1=new Bmw();
car1.setMake(2);

var car2=new Merc();
car2.setMake(3);

console.log(car1.getMake(),car2.getMake());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Car = function(){
    var self=this;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    var make=1;
    Car.prototype.getMake = function() {
        return make;
    };
    Car.prototype.setMake = function(val) {
        make=val;
        return make;
    };
};
```

does not make sense. `Car.prototype.getMake` affects every single instance of `Car`, so what you are basically saying is, every time a `new Car()` instance is created, change the `getMake` and `setMake` function on ALL instances back to `1`. Then when you call `setMake` it changes the `make` value for every instance

You either need to assign them explicitly to a single instance of `Car`. e.g.

```
var Car = function(){
    EventEmitter.call(this);

    var make=1;
    this.getMake = function() {
        return make;
    };
    this.setMake = function(val) {
        make=val;
        return make;
    };
};
```

Or keep them on the prototype and use a different method for passing the value of `make` into the functions.

```
var Car = function(){
    var self=this;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.make_ = 1;
};

Car.prototype.getMake = function() {
    return this.make_;
};
Car.prototype.setMake = function(val) {
    this.make_ = val;
    return this.make_;
};
```